# Can we reverse the effects of Global Warming?

Tags: technology, technological-development, climate-change

The base of this question is:  Are there currently any technology countermeasures in effect or under development to counter the effects of man-made global warming? (I do not know if there are, or how many)

If they make up a feedback system then the last question is:

```
Can we reverse Effect of Global Warming ?
```

Comment: Welcome to the site Catalin, I made some modifications to your post to help with clarity and readability, if you feel the changes have altered the intent of your question please feel free to revert the changes.  When you have a chance check out the [help] for more information on the site.

Comment: I recommend moving this to Earth Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: I recommend leaving this here. I think the question is about building a world in which the society design, build, did it, or is in process of, making a technology to achieve that goal. Even more, there is at least a movie which plot turns around that.

Comment: If this really is about building a fictional world, it should be made more clear. And more room for fiction would be a good idea. For now, this is just a query about real world research and nothing more. Thing like "what tech could believably be developed to help with global warming", or sth, would be better suited here :)

Comment: NASA -Global Temperature - http://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/global-temperature and the solutions:  Mitigation and Adaptation,
Government Resources and Energy Innovations, but nothing about world population reached 7 Billion versus that Global Temperature or something like that.

Comment: There is this project, which aims to reflect sunlight in the upper atmosphere.  https://spectrum.ieee.org/solar-geoengineering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the world is warming because of an increase of CO2 in the atmosphere, then removal of CO2 would tend to undo that effect.  One could remove CO2 from the atmosphere, or prevent additional CO2 from being added to the atmosphere.

A society can build vast CO2 scrubbers which removes CO2 by chemical reaction or by reversibly binding CO2 to a substance, then sequestering the CO2.  Nature has a wonderful CO2 scrubbing system called [Photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis) which converts CO2 and water to Oxygen and sugar.

Comment: I mean countermeasures, not natural process, maybe like index of conversion or efficiency of performance to reflect that, I know the theory.

Comment: @CătălinGeorgeFeștilă Does `build vast CO2 scrubbers` not count as a countermeasure? I think the photosynthesis references was just an idea for a chemical reaction that could be employed by these

Comment: I remember there was one idea of growing lumber then burying it to lock away the carbon. http://www.umerc.umd.edu/projects/sequestration01